# XmlReader Lags on first use Android c#

Tags: c#, android, xml, xmlreader

My problem is described in title. The main idea is that when I use my XmlReader for the first time it lags for some time, but then works normally, and other callings for my reader take no problems.
I use that call for XmlReader

```
string url = "https://google.com/SomeXml.aspx";
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url))//it stops here when first call
{
    while (reader.Read())
    { //reading file from url
    }
}
```

The question is why is it happening?
I have searched for this but found nothing.

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in the question for a proper answer.  Have you tried profiling or debugging?  What does the XML look like?  It might just be that time is required to load the requisite assemblies, see [Loading assemblies in the background so that it does not block UI thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/14162/loading-assemblies-in-the-background-so-that-it-does-not-block-ui-thread).

Comment: is the file size the same for first and subsequent xml? The first connection could take longer than rest due to credentials.  The first connection will get credentials and store as a cookie.  Then subsequent connections will use same cookie.  If you run application twice in a row do you get same delay?  Does issue only occur when you first turn on Android?  Does the Android delete cookies when power up/down?

Comment: yes, file size is same anyway. that issue comes only when application is started (from closed condition) and I'm trying to use that reader.
It doesnot metter from what activity i do it, I use XmlReader from one class, but different methods (it's not global), ech of them works only with one activity.